# Calculated timedelta column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have some data in a pandas df like:

```
time                            delay 
2017/06/14 10:02:10.144927 PM   15
```

The time is obviously a timestamp and in the delay is in seconds. `df.dtypes` are `datetime64[ns]` and `int` respectively. I want to add a column that has the timestamp of the original time plus the seconds passed, e.g.:

```
time                            delay   end_time
2017/06/14 10:02:10.144927 PM   15      2017/06/14 10:02:25.144927 PM
```

I'm trying to do

```
df["end_time"] = df.time.add(datetime.timedelta(seconds = df.time))
```

However I get an error `TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: Series`. How would I do this? Do I need a lambda?

Comment: `df.time` is a series of numbers. I think you wanted this to be element wise right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for convert integer column to timedeltas:

```
df["end_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).add(pd.to_timedelta(df.delay, unit='s'))
print (df)
                            time  delay                   end_time
0  2017/06/14 10:02:10.144927 PM     15 2017-06-14 22:02:25.144927
```

If need same format in output add [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df["end_time"] = (pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
                   .add(pd.to_timedelta(df.delay, unit='s'))
                   .dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f %p'))
print (df)
                            time  delay                       end_time
0  2017/06/14 10:02:10.144927 PM     15  2017/06/14 22:02:25.144927 PM
```